# Python : How to store output of each process during multiprocessing in a list

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

```
listJobRunIds = []
    
def run_job(dataset_date):
    command = START_JOB_RUN.format(dataset_date=dataset_date)
    jobRunId =  execute(command=command)
    print("jobRunId:"+jobRunId)
    listJobRunIds.append(jobRunId)
    print(listJobRunIds)
    time.sleep(60)
    return jobRunId

pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=3)

listJobRunDates = ['2022-10-01','2022-10-02','2022-10-03','2022-10-04'...]
jobRunId = pool.map(run_job, listJobRunDates)

print(jobRunId)
```

a. Only 3 process should run in a parallel

b. The execute function runs the job and returns the job run ID.

Date , JobrunId

2022-10-01 , 56728389

2022-10-02 , 56728390

2022-10-03 , 56728391

2022-10-04 , 56728392

c. Actually , once the execution of first pool completes(for first 3 run date and so on) , I want to print their job run IDs in the list
listJobRunIds :[56728389,56728390,56728391]

But using the above code ,I am just able to print the last job run ID after every pool

The final `print(jobRunId)` is giving the list with all the job run IDs like :
[56728389,56728390,56728391,56728392,56728393,56728394]

> My use case is  - once the 1st set of 3 job run complete, then only I
> want the second set of job run to execute. I am looking for 1st set of
> values in a list so that I can check the status(RUNNING,SUCCESS) of
> each jobrunid in a separate function. That new function I will call
> inside the job_run function after sleep(60)

Comment: Multiple processes **do not share state**

Comment: the above code will result in a name error because `jobRunId` is not defined anywhere, please modify it to reproduce the issue, also you seem to want to print `job_execution` variable instead ... also each process in multiprocessing has its separate part of memory with separate variables, and only arguments and returns are passed between these processes.

Comment: You may be looking for `for jobRunId in pool.imap(run_job, listJobRunDates): print(jobRunId)`.

Comment: @tdelaney - the `pool.imap(run_job, listJobRunDates):` is printing just the one jobRunId at a time - 56728389. I am looking for something where it print 1st set of 3 job runId at a time.[56728389,56728390,56728391]

Comment: then accumulate 3 and then print.

Comment: My use case is  - once the 1st set of 3 job run complete, then only I want the second set of job run to execute. I am looking for 1st set of values in a list so that I can check the status(RUNNING,SUCCESS) of each jobrunid in a separate function. That new function I will call inside the job_run function after sleep(60)

Comment: @tdelaney - It is accumulating all six (if I pass 6 dates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to process in groups of 3, split the list and then map. You could count wanted indexes by 3 and use that to pull sections.

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=3)

listJobRunDates = ['2022-10-01','2022-10-02','2022-10-03','2022-10-04'...]

for i in range(0, len(listJobRunDates, 3)):
    job_dates = listJobRunDates[i:i+3]
    print("Processing", job_dates)
    jobRunIds = pool.map(run_job, job_dates)
    for jobRunId in jobRunIds:
        print("Job id", jobRunId)
```